# Проблема с настройкой ipvlan для KVM

Tags: linux, сеть, виртуальная-машина, виртуализация, kvm

Моя проблема заключается в следующем: провожу настройку ipvlan для доступа к гостевым ОС через wlan0, настройка проводиться с помощью скрипта, который срабатывает при загрузке системы с помощью юнита systemd, интерфейс создается и поднимается, ему присваивается ip-адрес, но в KVM к гостевой ОС этот ipvlan невозможно подключить.
При выборе ipvlan в качестве мостового устройства

```
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:b6:c4:71"/>
  <source bridge="wlan0"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

выходит ошибка "не удалось добавить мост wlan0 (порт vnet0) неподдерживаемая операция"

При выборе ipvlan как устройства macvtap

```
<interface type="direct">
  <mac address="52:54:00:b6:c4:71"/>
  <source dev="wlan0" mode="bridge"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

ошибка "macvtap@wlan0 устройство или ресурс занято"

Однако macvlan работает, но это совсем не то что мне нужно, так как для беспроводных точек доступа вариант настройки с macvlan не работает, а указание в sysctl proxy_arp (как например в этом варианте https://vankevich.ru/blog/nastrojka-seti-kvm-v-rezhime-bridge-dlja-wi-fi/) для wlan0 не дает результата, так как wlan0 не pci-карта на моем хосте. Также, это не работает в случае с маршрутизатором работающем не в режиме точки доступа.

```
#!/bin/sh

HWLINK=wlan0
IPVLAN=ipvlan0
TESTHOST=ya.ru

# ------------
# test if interface already exists
# ------------
if ip link show | grep "$IPVLAN@$HWLINK" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Link $MACVLN already exists on $HWLINK."
    exit
fi

# ------------
# wait for network availability
# ------------

while ! ping -q -c 1 $TESTHOST > /dev/null
do
    echo "$0: Cannot ping $TESTHOST, waiting another 5 seconds."
    sleep 5
done

# ------------
# get network config
# ------------

IP=$(ip a sh wlan0 | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | head -1)
NETWORK=$(ip -o route | grep $HWLINK | grep -v default | awk '{print $1}')
GATEWAY=$(ip -o route | grep default | awk '{print $3}')

# ------------
# setting up $MACVLN interface
# ------------

ip link add $IPVLAN link $HWLINK type ipvlan mode l2
ip address add $IP dev $MACVLN
ip link set dev $IPVLAN up

# ------------
# routing table
# ------------

# empty routes
ip route flush dev $HWLINK
ip route flush dev $IPVLAN

# add routes
ip route add $NETWORK dev $IPVLAN metric 0

# add the default gateway
ip route add default via $GATEWAY
```

```
ip a sh ipvlan0
4: ipvlan0@wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:a9:fb:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.22/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute ipvlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e698:b2cb:334:265f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b827:eb00:1a9:fb8f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: А роутинг чем не угодил?

Comment: Чем маршрутизация не угодила ? Неужели вы не читали ? Я же написал, для нее требуется выставить proxy_arp в 1 для wlan0, что не дало результата, вернее раньше на давало результата потому что карта не pci сейчас, из-за того что маршрутизатор не в режиме точки доступа.  И вопрос сводится у тому как использовать интерфейс wlan0 в режиме схожем с macvlan и привязать его к виртуальной машине в KVM  ? Я поправлю вопрос.

Comment: причем тут проксиарп? я про настоящую маршрутизацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая ошибка это  - wlan не может бытьбриджом. создайте бридж и добавьте в него wlan.

Но тут возникнет проблема в том что на wlan в режиме sta можно передавать только один мак адрес. Тут или перевести в режим station wds или инкапсулировать мак в мак или в ip туннель.

Не советую делать бриджи и маквлан на вайфай. Но если карточка умеет wds, то шансы есть. Но почему-то эту технологию используют реже и реже. В современных репитерах ставят псевдобридж с проксиарп.

Для ipvlan понадобится proxyarp, если нет возможности настроить маршрутизацию на роутере. Если проксиарп не работает, то на роутере добавьте маршрут ип_гостя через ип_хоста.

Гостевые ИП лучше выделить в отдельную подсеть, тогда проксиарп уже не понадобится вовсе.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Хотя у меня карточка отказалась работать как с бриджом на вайфай, так с маквланом, было решено отказаться от macvlan и ipvlan вовсе, отключить прокси арп и сделать в kvm новое устройство virbrN с маршрутизацией на wlan0 и связать с virbrN с wlan0 с помощью parprouted, в итоге появилась связь между ВМ на разных хостах и отпала необходимость настраивать маршруты на роутере

Comment: При этом ВМ с сетью на virbrN находятся в подсети 192.168.1.96/27, а реальные машины в подсети 192.168.1.0/24, я понимаю что это не самое лучшее решение из-за возможных конфликтов ip-адресов, но это работает и таким костылем я пока удовлетворен

Answer (score 0):

Я оставлю этот ответ больше как заметку. Так как из-за возможных проблем описанных в предыдущем ответе я предлагаю более простое решение, которое не потребует заводить маршруты на маршрутизаторе.
Для этого уйти от использования ipvlan, создать в KVM новый интерфейс virbr с маршрутизацией на wlan0, затем связать wlan0 и virbr командой
sudo parprouted virbrN wlan0